# Dynamically generating functions in Python class

Tags: python

I'm looking for a more dynamic approach to generate these functions programmatically, as all of them essentially involve invoking the send_otp method with different ReasonOptions.
(And I don't want to set the ReasonOptions where I call them)

```
class OtpBusinessLogicLayer(Manager, BaseOtp):
    def send_forget_password_otp(self, identifier):
        return self.send_otp(identifier, reason=ReasonOptions.FORGET_PASSWORD)

    def send_phone_number_activation_otp(self, phone_number: str):
        return self.send_otp(phone_number, reason=ReasonOptions.PHONE_NUMBER_ACTIVATION)

    def send_two_step_auth_activation_otp(self, email: str):
        return self.send_otp(email, reason=ReasonOptions.ENABLE_TWO_STEP_AUTH)

    def send_two_step_auth_deactivation_otp(self, email: str):
        return self.send_otp(email, reason=ReasonOptions.DISABLE_TWO_STEP_AUTH)

    def send_change_user_identifier_otp(self, email: str):
        return self.send_otp(email, reason=ReasonOptions.CHANGE_USER_IDENTIFIER)
```

Comment: I'm perfectly happy with @Barmar's answer below.  However is this toy code or actual production code? Whoever has to maintain this code will curse you when they're looking for the definition of `send_two_step_auth_activation_opt` and can't find it.  If you need to write fifty of these, then yeah.  Four of five? Just write them out and keep it simple.

Comment: @FrankYellin Agree on that, first it was only 3 and now it went up to 9 and probably gonna go higher, that's why I'm looking for a way to improve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over a list of all the reason names and generate functions with `lambda`.

```
class OtpBusinessLogicLayer(Manager, BaseOtp):
    pass

reasons = ['forget_password', 'phone_number_activation', ...]
for r in reasons:
    setattr(OtpBusinessLogicLayer, f'send_{r}_otp', lambda self, identifier, r=r: elf.send_otp(identifier, reason=getattr(ReasonOptions, r.upper()))
```

See [What do lambda function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture) for an explanation of `r=r` in the `lambda`.

Comment: Beautiful, but is there any way so I can type them? so whenever some one calls them like `OtpBusinessLogicLayer().send_two_step_auth_activation_otp` knows exactly whats happening? any idea for simpilification?

Comment: Do you really need multiple methods? The solution in the other answer is simpler and the way I think most would do it.

Comment: ye that's the first thing I thought, I'm just trying to avoid giving reasons explicitly wherever i want to call otp (there are a lot of them).

Comment: How is that any different from calling the method name explicitly?

Comment: I.e. what makes `send_forget_password_otp(...)` better than `send_otp("forget_password", ...)`?

Comment: just extra argument on 50 other places that im using it, and extra imports (ReasonOptions), so extra code, buy i see what u mean.

Comment: @BadBoy There's no extra imports, the caller doesn't need `ReasonOptions`. They're all hidden inside the code of `send_otp`.

Comment: ReasonOptions is just an enum for better representation, wherever i need to use default strings i use enums and avoid sth like `send_otp("forget_password", ...)` and i do it like: `send_otp(ReasonOptions.FORGET_PASSWORD, ...)`

Comment: My whole point is that if you're willing to hard-code a function name like `send_forget_password_otp`, there's little difference from hard-coding a string literal.

Comment: well its not about the hard coding, my enum has a verbose_name into it as well and i want to have all the choices at one place (documentations, easy removal or adding new choices, and other features)

Comment: But you said you don't want the caller to know about the enum. They just call the method by name. And if they can call the method by name, they can use the string that's identical to the method name.

Comment: I guess so, I understand your point, that just been the way that i coded for long time that's why I'm used to it and now trying to do the same and go with use functions rather that arguments. but that's why i asked if i can type it or make it easier for others to understand your code

Answer (score 0):

In this solution I used a dictionary to map all the reasons to a corresponding `ReasonOptions` value. Now the function takes in a new value called `reason_` which should be either "phonenumber", "authactivation", "authdeactivaion" or "changeidentifier"

If the reason provided is invalid its going to return None. You should probably make the rest of your code work if it returns nothing aswell.

```
def send_data(self, value: str, reason_: str):
    reasons: dict = {"phonenumber": ReasonOptions.PHONE_NUMBER_ACTIVATION, 
                     "authactivation": ReasonOptions.ENABLE_TWO_STEP_AUTH,
                     "authdeactivation": ReasonOptions.DISABLE_TWO_STEP_AUTH,
                     "changeidentifier": ReasonOptions.CHANGE_USER_IDENTIFIER}
    reason = reasons.get(reason_.lower(), None)
    if reason == None:
        return

    return self.send_otp(value, reason=reason)
```